# using Iterators to get a particular sequence of list from [1, 2, 3]

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I want to achieve this output

```
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

from this given list: `[1,2,3]`.

I have tried using

```
foo = [1, 2, 2]
print(list(permutations(foo, 3)))
```

and this

l

```
ist(it.combinations_with_replacement([1,2,3], 3))

from itertools import combinations 
  
def rSubset(arr, r): 
   
    return list(combinations(arr, r)) 
  
 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    arr = [1, 2, 3] 
    r = 3
    print (rSubset(arr, r))
```

but am not able to get the required result any help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a *product*, not a permutation or combination.

```
from itertools import product

print(list(product([1,2,3], repeat=3)))
```